# removing items from NSmutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have two nsmutablearrays

> array1: searchedStores = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>
> array2: allStores;    ///it holds Stores information and it is also
>   NSMutableArray

Now if i add objects in "searchedStores" Array

```
for (int i= 0; i < [allstores count]; i++){
  Franchise *store = [allStores objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([store.ZipCode hasPrefix:str])  /// where str is searched string
    {
      [searchedStores addObject:store];    // some stores information will be inserted in "searchedStores" array
    }
}
```

Now if i remove objects from searchedStores array it will also remove objects from "allStores" array

to remove objects i am writing

```
[searchedStores removeAllObjects];
```

How can i remove objects only from "searchedStores" array. and "allStores" Array should keep its objects.

Comment: Removing items from one array, should not change the other array at all.  How are you creating and populating each array object?

Comment: Somewhere there must be a release too many or a retain too few. Squeegy is right, both arrays own (and retain) the objects they contain, so removing from one should not affect the other, so the problem must lie in the code that ran before that..

Comment: Please show where and how you initialize both `allStores` and `searchedStores`

Comment: i have solved this issue. yes i was releasing it. Thanks for all of your replys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are just assigning allstores array with searchedstores array then changes made in searched stores array will be reflected to allstores. You need to allocate new memory to allstores and then add objects from searchedstores array to it upon your logical behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Every array is totally independent. If removing objects from one array effects the other, you don't have two arrays, but only two pointers to the same array. You need to instantiate (alloc/init or mutableCopy) both. Feel free to show your initialization code as well.